# market filter, how to exclude layout-notlong

Tags: android, layout, google-play

I'm programming an app that is suitable only for devices that have long display. 
Now I'm looking after how to setup market filters to prevent download of an application to devices with nolong displays.

Is there a way to do so? Or I have to check aspect ratio in the application and pop an excuse note to user with not proper layout?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by long display?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean `long display`? If you mean large display, then you can set the `supports-screens` element in the manifest, specifying with true/false which screen sizes you support.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#small

Comment: Long display in mater of aspect ratio of 400*800. All devices with that aspect ratio are welcome. But device with aspect ratio of 240x320 won't work well. Maybe there I could exclude small screens but there will be still some tables with large resolution and this aspect ratio

Comment: Then simply add `<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" />` to your Manifest.

Comment: Thanks mate. As I have already checked for 100 times, there's no market filter for aspect ratio. I will excuse small size screens. For other screens I will check aspect ratio in the code and shrink graphics. Game will be not ideal but will be still payable :)

Comment: `xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp` http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @ LuxuryMode I red that article before posting. Maybe you got me wrong but I asked if there a filter for screen layout type "layout-notlong". And I done that exactly because it can't be covered with screen size filters. I have published 16 applications, but on 17th I find a need for filter this. Thanks dude